# Integrating MongoDB cloud with AWS autoscaling

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I am absolutely not buying Mongodb Atlas :) I want to make the best I can with MongoDB cloud. Today with MongoDB cloud, when I spin up an AWS instance the automation takes care of joining my MongoDB cloud account w/ the API and group key I've embedded in my system image. What I want to do now is take it to the next level and have that instance register itself as an additional replica of an -existing- replica set and sync up. I can't be the first person to want to do this but I'm coming up empty with Google. Can anyone point me to a gist, blog, rant or other example of how to do this?